# Детальный просмотр и цепочка навигации

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет!
Ребята, выручайте...

На странице http://site/training/articles/ у меня есть компонент `bitrix:news`. Компонент стандартный, шаблоны тоже не кастомизировал.
Урлы настроены так: http://my.jetscreenshot.com/13187/20141004-pwhb-28kb
Ну и если у меня есть статья с символьным кодом `article-1`, то она нормально отображалась по адресу http://site/training/articles/article-1/

Потом я решил поэкспериментировать с цепочками навигации и поставил всего одну галочку - http://my.jetscreenshot.com/13187/20141004-j6zo-29kb.
И теперь у меня на http://site/training/articles/ по-прежнему список статей, но если ткнуть на ссылку детального просмотра, то по http://site/training/articles/article-1/ я вижу почему-то мой http://site/index.php. Но самый трэш в том, что если эту галку обратно снять, то ничего уже не поменяется (по-прежнему вместо статьи вижу http://site/index.php)!

Подскажите, куда хоть копать? Как вернуть статьи хотя бы исходному состоянию?

P.S. Если из админки у статьи нажать просмотр (http://my.jetscreenshot.com/13187/20141004-5c8p-75kb), то тоже вместо статьи вижу http://site/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы было как раньше, вам нужно настроить урлы так: http://joxi.ru/wbcvVIwyTJDrAuu63NI

Т.е. путь "/training/articles/" должен быть только в поле "Каталог ЧПУ (относительно корня сайта)", в поле "Страница детального просмотра" должно быть "#ELEMENT_CODE#/", остальные поля - пустые.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло